# como sumar valores de un json pero cuando cumplan un criterio en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array, objeto

estoy obteniendo un json y quiero sumar los valores que trae en cada objeto pero siempre y cuando sean de la misma persona. obtener el nombre de los vendedores y el total de las ventas que tuvo pero por separado. esto lo estoy requiriendo por que estpy ocupando chart.js y en los labels quiero colocar el array de nombres y el los datasets colocar los valores de las ventas pero por persona este es mi json.

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "armando",
        "venta": 700,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "rosa",
        "venta": 400,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-03"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "pedro",
        "venta": 1600,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "rosa",
        "venta": 1600,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    }
]
```

lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente

```
vendedores = {"juan","armando","pedro","rosa"}
ventas = {1500,700,2000,1600}
```

lo que hasta ahorita eh echo:

```
//aqui obtengo solo los nombres sin repetir
 const nombres = data.map(x => x.nombre)
 const nombre = [... new Set(nombres)]
 // console.log(nombre)

//forEach 
 nombre.forEach(nom => {
 const filtro = data.filter(x => x.nombre == nom)
//realizo el filtro por vendedor y me da un array con cada objeto
/*(3) […]
0: Object { nombre: "juan", venta: 500, fecha: "2021-01-01" }
1: Object { nombre: "juan", venta: 500, fecha: "2021-01-02" }
2: Object { nombre: "juan", venta: 500, fecha: "2021-01-03" }
length: 3
<prototype>: [*/
const ventas = filtro.reduce((acc, valor) => acc + valor.venta, 0)
console.log(ventas)
/*aqui me da los valores de esta forma
1500
700
2000
600
pero son objetos

*/

 })
```

---

en el comentario que escribi donde al final de la pregunta coloque que me manda los resultados en objeto me refiero a esto, coloque un consol.log() y me da esto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
  let data = [
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "armando",
        "venta": 700,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "rosa",
        "venta": 400,
        "fecha": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "juan",
        "venta": 500,
        "fecha": "2021-01-03"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "pedro",
        "venta": 1600,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "rosa",
        "venta": 1600,
        "fecha": "2021-01-02"
    }
]


const datosVendedores = data =>{
    const nombres = data.map(x => x.nombre)
    const nombre = [... new Set(nombres)]
    // console.log(nombre)
    nombre.forEach(nom => {
        const filtro = data.filter(x => x.nombre == nom)
        // console.log(filtro)
        const ventas = filtro.reduce((acc, valor) => acc + valor.venta, 0)
        
        console.log(ventas)
    })
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="grafica"></canvas>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las mayúsculas sostenidas en internet son el equivalente a gritar. Tú crees que pedir ayuda gritándonos es buena idea? Por favor, edita la pregunta y utiliza las mayúsculas solo cuando necesites *resaltar* algo. Si ya tienes lo que necesitas... qué problema hay? Qué significa *PERO SON OBJETOS*??

Comment: No lo sabia amigo @Benito-B ya lo investigue y tienes razón, Gracias

Comment: perdón no era eso de son objetos, mando a imprimir en consola y me dan estos por cada persona, lo que estoy buscando es como meter cada resultado en un array por ejemplo ventas = {1500,700,2000,600} pero no se realizarlo, ya untente despues de la funcion reduce hacer un push a un array en blanco y si me salio pero como esta dentro del forEach lo hace cada vez que encuentra un dato, en esta plataforma tambien soy nuevo, quiero subir un foto para mostrar lo que obtengo pero no se como

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad ya casi lo tienes, has conseguido iterar sobre los objetos y sacar el array de nombres únicos, y luego has iterado de nuevo filtrando por nombre e imprimiendo los totales de ventas de cada nombre... lo único que te quedaba era ***guardar*** esos valores!

```js
// Array de datos
const data = [
  {
    nombre: "juan",
    venta: 500,
    fecha: "2021-01-01",
  },
  {
    nombre: "armando",
    venta: 700,
    fecha: "2021-01-01",
  },
  {
    nombre: "rosa",
    venta: 400,
    fecha: "2021-01-01",
  },
  {
    nombre: "juan",
    venta: 500,
    fecha: "2021-01-02",
  },
  {
    nombre: "juan",
    venta: 500,
    fecha: "2021-01-03",
  },
  {
    nombre: "pedro",
    venta: 1600,
    fecha: "2021-01-02",
  },
  {
    nombre: "rosa",
    venta: 1600,
    fecha: "2021-01-02",
  },
];
const nombres = data.map((x) => x.nombre);
// He cambiado el nombre de la variable nombre a arrayNombres, mucho más indicativo de su contenido!
const arrayNombres = [...new Set(nombres)];
// Se declara un arrayVentas vacío, aquí almacenaremos las ventas de cada uno
const arrayVentas = [];
arrayNombres.forEach((nom) => {
  const filtro = data.filter((x) => x.nombre == nom);
  const ventas = filtro.reduce((acc, valor) => acc + valor.venta, 0);
  // Hasta aquí es lo mismo que tenías tu!
  // Simplemente en vez de imprimirlo en consola, lo meto al array de ventas
  arrayVentas.push(ventas);
});
// Finalmente imprimimos en consola para verificar que todo ha ido bien
console.log(arrayNombres);
console.log(arrayVentas);
```

---

Te dejo en comentarios todos los cambios que hice explicados. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, ya quedo ya había intentado el .push pero no se por que no me salia, creo había colocado el array vació dentro del forEach pero ya quedo gracias!!!